# How do I share the same copy/paste clipboard between Centos and Vinagre Remote Desktop Viewer?

Tags: centos, remote-desktop

I am using Centos 8 and I am using the Vinagre Remote Desktop Viewer to access Windows 10 computer. Is there a way for me to share the copy/paste clipboard between the two? So I can just copy text,images,etc from Centos side and paste it immediately in Windows 10 side.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this doesn't work and has not for a long time according to this b[ug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vinagre/+bug/1312141).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: run this from a terminal window

```
xfreerdp /u:youruserid /v:yourdevice +clipboard
```

I cannot take credit for finding this, it was given to me by another system Admin